# Using Core Data as cache

Tags: macos, core-data, appkit

I am using Core Data for its storage features. At some point I make external API calls that require me to update the local object graph. My current (dumb) plan is to clear out all instances of old NSManagedObjects (regardless if they have been updated) and replace them with their new equivalents -- a trump merge policy of sorts.

I feel like there is a better way to do this. I have unique identifiers from the server, so I should be able to match them to my objects in the store. Is there a way to do this without manually fetching objects from the context by their identifiers and resetting each property? Is there a way for me to just create a completely new context, regenerate the object graph, and just give it to Core Data to merge based on their unique identifiers?

Comment: Apple has a good guide to the requirements-- [Efficiently Importing Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html). Especially check out the section called **Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently**.

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy of matching, based on the server's unique IDs, is a good approach. Hopefully you can get your server to deliver only the objects that have changed since the time of your last update (which you will keep track of, and provide in the server call).

In order to update the Core Data objects, though, you will have to fetch them, instantiate the NSManagedObjects, make the changes, and save them. You can do this all in a background thread (child context, `performBlock:`), but you'll still have to round-trip your objects into memory and back to store. Doing it in a child context and its own thread will keep your UI snappy, but you'll still have to do the processing.

Another idea: In the last day or so I've been reading about `AFIncrementalStore`, an `NSIncrementalStore` implementation which uses `AFNetworking` to provide Core Data properties on demand, caching locally. I haven't built anything with it yet but it looks pretty slick. It sounds like your project might be a good use of this library. Code is on GitHub: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore.

Comment: Hi Hal, I have been playing with AFIncrementalStore :) It does look pretty awesome, but unfortunately it would take a lot of time to roll my own store what with the dearth of example implementations out there. Even if I did implement my own store, I'm still not sure how that would help me with merging data from my "network" store with my local store. Either way, thanks for the tip!